# Coupling Teams to SO creates potential data leaks

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

SE decided to strongly couple Teams to Stack Overflow accounts. You need an SO account to participate in a private Team, and there is no way around this.

I find this decision quite odd, but while that is not the point, it also creates additional complications that I find rather problematic. One of the main issues is that this coupling forces everyone that uses a Team to create an SO account, and usually that is an SO account connected to your company email adress for authentication.

When I sign up for a private Q&A service, I expect this to be entirely private and I would expect that no part of this is accessible to anyone except my company and the relevant staff at SE. And while this is true for the actual Q&A content of Teams as far as I understand, the link to SO accounts does indeed leak certain kinds of activity from Teams.

A moderator can access PII of users on their site, so an SO moderator can access PII of anyone with an account on Stack Overflow. As Teams requires an SO account, this also includes everyone using a private Team. I don't think that is the expected behaviour if you buy a private Q&A site.

A more serious aspect here is that because the Teams authentication often works by email domain, the SO accounts are likely using all the same email domain. There is a way for moderators to query a lot of users at once by email address, as far as I understand this would in most cases allow a moderator to easily get a full list of all users belonging to a specific Team, including names and emails. That particular tool is problematic by itself, but it's particularly powerful if all people from a particular company sign up to SO with the same email address.

A major caveat here is as I'm not an SO mod, I have to make some assumptions here on how the system works compared to other SE sites. If my concerns are addresses by specific mechanisms that protect Teams, I'd consider this resolved.

Another thing I find rather odd is that visiting the main page of a Team updates the last seen indicator on your SO profile, which is publicly visible. That indicator is not always updated immediately, but as far as I can tell if I haven't visited SO in 10-15 minutes, it'll immediately switch to last seen a few seconds ago if I visit the moderator-only Team (not SO itself). I find it very odd that a visit to a private Q&A site would update a publicly visible field like this.

Together, these aspects indicate to me that the strong coupling between the public SO account and the private Teams account are inherently problematic. As a potential customer, this is really not what I expect from a typical SaaS service.

There are a lot of more subtle aspects to this, and the email part depends heavily on how people actually create their accounts and authenticate to Teams. But all those complicated parts are not something anyone outside SE can understand, and I don't see how users can make educated decisions here when the systems behind this are pretty much opaque.

What I would expect when I buy a private Q&A site is a completely private instance. I don't expect any public leaks of the existence of any accounts on that site, and certainly not any indication of specific points in time when people are active on it.

Comment: Interesting thought I just had-  if I work at Foo corp and use my personal SO account for Teams, then that SO account gets banned/deleted/other-  what happens to the team account?  I would not be happy as an employer to have employees unable to use the software, and my anger would be aimed at StackExchange.  And as a user, I would want to be able to kill my personal account without sacrificing the work one.  Although the practical answer to both of these is make a new work only account, and accept the karma loss.

Comment: @GabeSechan As far as I understand, a mod can't delete an account that is a member of a Team, and suspensions don't affect Teams.