# Using a personal Stack Overflow account for a Team potentially allows your employer to take it over

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, security, privacy

This is based on [this support request from fazy about several potential issues due to the fact that SO and Teams account are not separate entities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402374/what-visibility-control-do-stack-overflow-for-teams-admins-have-over-linked-acco). As this received no response, I tried one of the potential scenarios out myself.

It turns out that if you join a Team via a company email address while logged into Stack Overflow with a personal account, this allows anyone with access to your company email account to take over your private account. This is a straightforward consequence of the way SE accounts and logins work and the fact that the Teams account is not actually separate from the Stack overflow account. But I would argue that this is not an expected result for a typical user that isn't deeply familiar with these kinds of implementation details.

The following steps show how this works:

- Join a Team using your company email while logged into your personal Stack Overflow account
- Your personal Stack Overflow account will join the Team
- Your company email address will be automatically and silently added to your personal account
- Request a password reset using your company email address

Anyone that can redirect or access your company email account can take over your personal account with a simple password reset. You can prevent this by manually removing the login based on the company address as far as I can tell, but that is far from obvious to a typical user, especially as this login is added silently while joining a Team.

This issue also works in the other direction to some extent, as it means that the Teams administrator can't control all pathways to password resets. So e.g. if you have a strong 2FA policy on your company email account, this still could leave a weak private email account as an attack vector to your Team. Especially since the default login method by SE doesn't even have the option to add any 2FA method, and a site like Stack Overflow might not be one where you use your strongest password.

I think it is a very surprising and unexpected result that joining a Team gives your employer the possibility to access your personal Stack Overflow account. While I think the true solution is to treat Teams as a completely separate account, this is unlikely to be feasible. But SE should add some mitigations to prevent these potential issues.

One option would be to directly ask the user if they actually want to link their current account to the team, and inform them about the consequences of doing so. That dialog could also offer alternatives like creating an entirely separate account or using the existing account while not adding the company email as a login.

I find the total silence from SE on what is arguably a security and privacy issue to be rather disappointing.

Comment: When an admin can do this, when I wonder what will happen if one leaves the company. Is the account only kicked from Teams or can they deactivate the whole account?

Comment: @Tom The deactivation tool in Teams only disables the access to the Team, it has no effect on the account itself.

Comment: Well that's good to hear. So the usual processes are kind of ok. That an admin reset your password to take the account other is unlikely, I guess.

Comment: For EU data subjects (and the UK until or unless legislation diverges), it is doubtful that this complies with Article 32 of the GDPR. Given that data subjects weren't informed about the linking, it probably also violates GDPR Article 13.

Comment: The accounts are irrevocably linked.
1. "Edit profile and settings"
2. "Edit Email Settings" shows my work email and a message "You can’t change your email address while single sign-on is enabled"
3. "My Teams", find team for work and "Leave team"
4. Log out all SO sites
5. Access a link to work team, "Join team"
6. Follow activation link from email (in work inbox)
You now have full access to your personal account again through your work inbox/SSO.

Comment: A friendly admin at my company deleted my user from the Teams instance. Now my answers remain but linked to `user##` (some number). He then invited my work email to join the team and I accepted - in a totally different browser and private browsing mode. I now have private browsing tabs open in Chrome - logged into personal account, shows as a member of the work team _again_. In Firefox - logged into work account, links to my personal account but only shows public content.

Comment: In my private Chrome tab, clicking the team offers to sign in with SSO (I'm not signed in). I worry that if I do so, it will deepen the link and allow full access to my personal account from the work one. *Edit:* However, the password reset still works: I can reset my personal account password using my work email account, even though I don't have a work password (it uses Okta SSO).

Comment: @Catija any update on this?

Comment: @Braiam There's changes coming in the next couple of quarters that, I think, will fix this to some extent for Business teams (they don't apply to Basic). But I don't know the timeline or how much I can discuss at this point.

Comment: Can this be avoided by just logging out of SO before you click the "join" link in the work email?

Comment: #Metoo. @Juice. What if one leaves the company? And what happens with all of us who only discovered this *after* the fact? ****How do we unlink our personal SO accounts from our company's? **** Anyone from StackOverflow ???

Comment: And what if we go to another company that also uses this feature? Wouldn't the new company be able to access the private chats of the previous company thru the employee who left, for example?? @StackOverflow: *You need to provide a solution*. And the solution is, IMHO to be able to remove yourself from the company's teams through your *personal* account. How difficult is this folks?

Comment: @Pap You can remove a Team from your personal account. The option has been there since Teams were released. It's under https://stackoverflow.com/users/teams/mine//{userid}

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Yes, if your company account is compromised, it is possible for someone to access and take over your personal account. Should this happen, we’ll of course work with the user to restore access to their personal account.

We agree it wasn’t very clear that you would be joining the team with your Public SO account, but the join flow has now been updated to make this explicit.

Comment: The "your company account is compromised" statement is a bit ambiguous, the case I was thinking of was not the account being compromised itself, but that anyone that can control the company email addresses or the SSO would inherently be able to reset my password, is my understanding here still correct? And is the other way around, accessing the company Teams via private accounts something a Teams admin could prohibit by policy?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. Regardless of how, should anyone at your company access your account and remove your ability to use your public profile, we would rectify that issue. No, a Team admin cannot prohibit a user from adding private Teams credentials to their public SO account.

Comment: @MadScientist If someone else in your company with any-time access to your email (should be very few, very specific IT people... like 5 or fewer for a company of thousands) resets your Stack Overflow Teams password using that email and then accesses/redirects the automated email, that would definitely be an "account compromised" situation, as they definitely shouldn't be doing it. And you should definitely report it to the appropriate company security office for abuse of IT access.

Comment: I think what Juice said: _"No, a Team admin cannot prohibit a user from adding private Teams credentials to their public SO account."_ could do with more emphasis. __Don't use your _private_ account for work stuff!__ You don't expect to work there for life, so get a new account for that!

Comment: @Cerbrus I fully agree with that, and that is what I would personally do. The problem is that SE encourages mixing SO accounts and Teams accounts, which makes it easy to violate this rule. And I would suspect that many users would assume that the Teams account is a separate thing from the SO account, it is not that obvious that they would be linked in this way.

Comment: "Regardless of how, should anyone at your company access your account and remove your ability to use your public profile, we would rectify that issue."

Wow. I mean seriously, Wow and wow again. Please tell me I understand this correctly. You acknowledge a security flaw, and then tell us that in the event of a data breach, you will rectify it. Please confirm that rectifying it would include SO providing compensation in line with GDPR Article 82.

Does SO plan to fix this flaw?

Comment: This *feature* is a trap!